# WPF add c# code to customcontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, generics

I want to create simple custom control (derived from control and with look defined in generics.xaml). 
I need to change size of elements defined in generic.xaml, when control is resized! It would be great to write some of that generic.xaml part in C#. Is that possible? Or is there a way to create MVVM like custom control?
What i am willing to create is simple blinking led control (on,blinking, off).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's more than one question in your post, but I'll answer the pertinent one: can you supplement your generic.xaml with code.

The answer is yes. Simply add generic.xaml.cs and marry the two up the same way UserControls are. That is:

1. Specify x:class in your generic.xaml
2. Declare your code-behind as a partial class
3. Ensure your partial class inherits from `ResourceDictionary`

Comment: Hmm..
I was expecting to have more fun there (c#).
Can i get similar functionality in general.xaml.cs as in usercontrol class (override onrendersize, add event handlers, access elements by name?!)

Comment: Overriding OnRenderSize wouldn't make sense for a ResourceDictionary. You can do stuff like add event handlers, or add your own items to the RD via code rather than XAML.